# AsyncTask slow with OnClick

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

Goodmorning,
I have a button on my android app that launches a search on the web (through google endpoints) through an AsyncTask. My problem is that the button does not "unclick" until the AsyncTask is completed, which may take several seconds. When the internet connection is slow, this even makes the application crash, in any case the application is completely stuck until the AsyncTask is completed. Now the reason for using AsyncTask was exactly to eliminate this problem, so I don't really get what happens!

Here is the OnClickListener:

```
SearchListener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {     
      String cname=TextCourse.getText().toString();
      if (!cname.isEmpty()){
          try {
              CollectionResponseWine listavini= new QueryWinesTask(messageEndpoint,cname,5).execute().get();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              showDialog("Errore ricerca");
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
              showDialog("Errore ricerca");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }              
      } else{
          showDialog("Inserisci un piatto");
      }
  }
};
```

and here is the AsyncTask that is being called:

```
private class QueryWinesTask 
extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CollectionResponseWine> {
  Exception exceptionThrown = null;
  MessageEndpoint messageEndpoint;
  String cname;
  Integer limit;

  public QueryWinesTask(MessageEndpoint messageEndpoint, String cname, Integer limit) {
      this.messageEndpoint = messageEndpoint;
      this.cname=cname;
      this.limit=limit;
  }

  @Override
  protected CollectionResponseWine doInBackground(Void... params) {
      try {
          CollectionResponseWine wines = messageEndpoint.listwines().setCoursename(cname).setLimit(limit).execute();                    
          return wines;
      } catch (IOException e) {
          exceptionThrown = e;
          return null;
          //Handle exception in PostExecute
      }            
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(CollectionResponseWine wines) {
      // Check if exception was thrown
      if (exceptionThrown != null) {
          Log.e(RegisterActivity.class.getName(), 
                  "Exception when listing Messages", exceptionThrown);
          showDialog("Non ci sono vini associati al tuo piatto. Aggiungine uno!");
      }
      else {

          messageView.setText("Vini piu' votati per " + 
                  cname + ":\n\n");
          for(Wine wine : wines.getItems()) {
              messageView.append(wine.getName() + " (" + wine.getScore() + ")\n");
          }
      }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...execute().get()` is blocking. It makes UI thread wait for Task to complete.

Don't do `get()`. Use `onPostExecute()` to get the result (`wines`) of task and update the UI.